# Python: Summing every five rows of column b data and create a new column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like below. I would like to sum row 0 to 4 (every 5 rows) and create another column with summed value ("new column"). My real dataframe has 263 rows so, last three rows every 12 rows will be sum of three rows only. How I can do this using Pandas/Python. I have started to learn Python recently. Thanks for any advice in advance!

My data patterns is more complex as I am using the index as one of my column values and it repeats like:

```
Row Data "new column"   
0   5  
1   1  
2   3  
3   3  
4   2    14         
5   4  
6   8   
7   1  
8   2  
9   1    16
10  0
11  2
12  3     5
0   3  
1   1  
2   2  
3   3  
4   2    11         
5   2  
6   6   
7   2  
8   2  
9   1    13    
10  1
11  0
12  1    2
...
259 50   89
260 1
261 4
262 5    10
```

I tried iterrows and groupby but can't make it work so far.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
df['new col'] = df.groupby(df.index // 5)['Data'].transform('sum')[lambda x: ~(x.duplicated(keep='last'))]
```

Output:

```
   Data  new col
0     5      NaN
1     1      NaN
2     3      NaN
3     3      NaN
4     2     14.0
5     4      NaN
6     8      NaN
7     1      NaN
8     2      NaN
9     1     16.0
```

## Edit to handle updated question:

```
g = df.groupby(df.Row).cumcount()
df['new col'] = df.groupby([g, df.Row // 5])['Data']\
                  .transform('sum')[lambda x: ~(x.duplicated(keep='last'))]
```

Output:

```
    Row  Data  new col
0     0     5      NaN
1     1     1      NaN
2     2     3      NaN
3     3     3      NaN
4     4     2     14.0
5     5     4      NaN
6     6     8      NaN
7     7     1      NaN
8     8     2      NaN
9     9     1     16.0
10   10     0      NaN
11   11     2      NaN
12   12     3      5.0
13    0     3      NaN
14    1     1      NaN
15    2     2      NaN
16    3     3      NaN
17    4     2     11.0
18    5     2      NaN
19    6     6      NaN
20    7     2      NaN
21    8     2      NaN
22    9     1     13.0
23   10     1      NaN
24   11     0      NaN
25   12     1      2.0
```

Comment: That worked! But it turns out my data pattern is bit more complex. This code seems to sum all 0-4 rows together. How would I calculate the sum for every 0-4, 5-9 etc. separately?

Comment: @lukas, For a new question you should ask [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). If this answers your *original* question, you should accept it.

Comment: Thanks Scott for your code! I felt I need another index to group repeating row patterns and didn't know how. Your cumcount helped me to get that! Also, I picked up more understanding on the transform and duplicated. The only thing is my real data generated lot of same 'new col' values toward the end of rows so lambda function didn't work well. But I get by with selecting only rows I need after doing transform(sum). Guess it is not pythonic way but I am still learning :-). Thanks for the help!