# Pandas vectorized way to create groups of size n?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

Say I have a huge tensor of shape `(samples, timesteps, features)`, but I want to unroll it to perform `groupby` operations with Pandas, how can I label every n:n+size elements accordingly, in a vectorized fashion? Slow solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(0, 1, 500))
df["sample"] = np.nan

n_timesteps = 50
n_samples = len(df) // n_timesteps

size = n_timesteps
for i in range(n_samples):
    id0 = i * n_timesteps
    id1 = i * n_timesteps + n_timesteps
    df.loc[id0:id1, "sample"] = i
```

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52066812/python-summing-every-five-rows-of-column-b-data-and-create-a-new-column)

Answer (score 2):

Assign new column by integer division with `index`:

```
#default RangeIndex
df['sample'] = df.index // n_timesteps
```

Or by 1d numpy array created by `arange`:

```
df['sample'] = np.arange(len(df)) // n_timesteps
```